# Deeplearning4j vs R results differ

Tags: deeplearning4j

I believe that deeplearning4j and R with exactly the same parameters should perform the same, comparable MSE. But I am not sure how to achieve that.

I have a csv file with the following format, which contains `46` variables and `2` outputs. Totally there are `1,0000` samples. All the data is normalized and the model is for regression analysis.

```
S1  |  S2  |  ...  |  S46  |  X  |  Y
```

In R, I use `neuralnet` package, and the code is:

```
rn <- colnames(traindata)
f <- as.formula(paste("X + Y ~", paste(rn[1:(length(rn)-2)], collapse="+")))
nn <- neuralnet(f, 
                rep=1,
                data=traindata, 
                hidden=c(10), 
                linear.output=T,
                threshold = 0.5)
```

which is quite straightforward.

As I want to integrate the algorithm into Java project, so I consider dl4j to train the model. The trainset is exactly the same as that in R code. The test set is randomly selected. THe dl4j code is:

```
MultiLayerConfiguration conf = new NeuralNetConfiguration.Builder()
            .seed(rngSeed) //include a random seed for reproducibility
            // use stochastic gradient descent as an optimization algorithm
            .optimizationAlgo(OptimizationAlgorithm.STOCHASTIC_GRADIENT_DESCENT)
            .iterations(100)
            .learningRate(0.0001) //specify the learning rate
            .updater(Updater.NESTEROVS).momentum(0.9) //specify the rate of change of the learning rate.
            .regularization(true).l2(0.0001)
            .list()
            .layer(0, new DenseLayer.Builder() //create the first, input layer with xavier initialization
                    .nIn(46)
                    .nOut(10)
                    .activation(Activation.TANH)
                    .weightInit(WeightInit.XAVIER)
                    .build())
            .layer(1, new OutputLayer.Builder(LossFunctions.LossFunction.MSE) //create hidden layer
                    .nIn(10)
                    .nOut(outputNum)
                    .activation(Activation.IDENTITY)
                    .build())
            .pretrain(false).backprop(true) //use backpropagation to adjust weights
            .build();
```

The number of epoch is 10 and batchsize is 128.

Using the test set, the performance of R is
[image]

and the performance of dl4j is the following, I think it does not work out its full potential.
[image]

The mornitor of dl4j is

[image]

As there is much more parameters in dl4j such as `updater`, `regulization` and `weightInit`. So I think some of the parameters are not properly set. BTW, why there are periodic thorns in the mornitor graph.

Can any one help?

Answer (score 1):

Most neural net training happens in minibatches. Deeplearning4j assumes you aren't doing toy problems by default (all data in memory < 10 examples etc)

The neural net config has a function called minibatch you should look for.

Set minibatch to false on the configuration and you should get the same results.

If you're wondering why this happens, it's because minibatch learning is different from doing everything in memory. Minibatch learning automatically divides the gradient by the minibatch size. When you do everything in memory you don't want that.

Take note of this when you're running other experiments.
For more on this see:
https://deeplearning4j.org/toyproblems